# Azure pipeline wasn't triggered when the PR move from draft to open

Tags: github, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

am experiencing an issue with the Azure pipeline wasn't triggered when the PR moved from draft to open
Here is the yaml configuration I used:

trigger: none

```
pr:
    drafts: false
    branches:
        include:
            - main
            - hotfix/*
```

does anyone has idea what is going wrong with it?

Comment: Is your repo hosted in Azure DevOps or in GitHub/BitBucket?

Comment: My repo is hosted on Github